# array_push doesn't push the value into array and prints only last pushed value

Tags: php, array-push

array_push returns only last value that has been currently pushed into the array in php. Please help. Here is the link where I am working http://dev.optimizebusinessgrowth.com/gopaperboy/members/
Its an jquery ajax. I call ajax with

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('.icon-heart').click(function(){

    var user_IDs = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var current_IDs = <?php echo $cui ?>;

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'ajaxreturn=101&id='+user_IDs+'&myid='+current_IDs,
        success: function(result){
          jQuery('.testres').html(result);
        }

    });//ajax ends here 
  });
});
```

and here is the code in function.php which gives response

```
function my_ajaxreturn_101() {
  $current_fav = array();
  if($_POST['ajaxreturn']==101) {

    $userID = $_POST['id']; 
    $loggedID = $_POST['myid'];

    array_push($current_fav,$userID);
    print_r($current_fav);
    exit;

  }

}
```

Comment: Is this `PHP`? Please add a tag for your programming language.

Comment: because you redefine `$current_fav` each time the function is called, so it's a new array every time, aka "last value"

Comment: Where did you print the array?

Comment: Actually here is the link where I am working. http://dev.optimizebusinessgrowth.com/gopaperboy/members/

Comment: Its jquery ajax. I call ajax by this

Comment: Now I have added the whole code along with link where I am working. You can check the live code working by clicking on heart icon in each member box. Thanks for you replay.

Comment: To further what @eric.itzhak says, you're not only redefining the array, you're exiting after the function runs just once. Based on that, you'll only ever have one element in the array.

Comment: OK, Can you help me how to redefine? Can you write a little bit of code here for me.? thnaks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `append()` instead of `html()`, so you can do:

```
jQuery('.testres').append(result);
```

instead of:

```
jQuery('.testres').html(result);
```

Comment: append again appends an array with the same value. I just print the value in .testres in order to determine whether the data is being pushed into the array or not. after that I will insert it into the database by serializing it. thanks